# SharePoint Server 2013- How to edit an InfoPath Form that has been Published to a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, edit

We have users fill out InfoPath Forms which get published to a document library in SharePoint. How do I edit the InfoPath form after it is published to a library?
I tried downloading a copy of the form but it opens on read only mode. I tried editing in the Browser but that doesn't work either.

I have the Form Template saved locally but I want to specifically make changes to a form that a user has submitted. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a changes in form which has some user created, it is not working with the template in the library, but with the document which was created from the template.

So you must download the file as document in the library and change the inner XML, save it and upload to the library again.

Or you can use Powershell and edit XML through it.
Example [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905396/using-powershell-to-read-modify-rewrite-sharepoint-xml-document).